# Using biginteger to find the sequence of sum of powers

Tags: java, biginteger, power-series

```
Sum(N) =1^1+2^2+3^3+...+N^N
```

Using Java, 
How would I use `BigInteger` to find the smallest integer N such that the value of Sum(N) is larger than 10^20?
I'm really stuck,please give me some advice

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
public class PROJECTV1 {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        BigInteger bResult= bigFunctionExample_2();
        System.out.println(" => result_got:"+ bResult);
        System.out.println(); //newline
    }// end_main 

    public static BigInteger bigFunctionExample_2() {
        BigInteger bSum = BigInteger.ZERO;
        BigInteger bTmp;
        String sSum;
        // BigInteger bResult =0;
        for (int i=1; ; i++) {
            bTmp = BigInteger.valueOf(i);
            bTmp = bTmp.pow(i); // i^i
            bSum = bSum.add(bTmp); // sum = i^i+ (i-1)^(i-1)+ ....
            sSum = bSum.toString();
            if ( sSum.length() >21) {
                System.out.println("i="+i +" bSum ="+bSum);
                break;
            }//
        }//end_for
        return bSum; // result
    } // end_bigFunctionExample_2
}
```

Comment: its easy man, a double for-loop would do the trick, but atleast try something on your own

Comment: A first step may be to first printOut arbitrary outputs, IE calc and show

Comment: Well, the first step is to write a `public static void main(String[] args)` method... oh, what, you've done that already? Well how would I know unless you show us where it is you're stuck?

Comment: How would you do this if you had to do it yourself with pencil and paper?  (And change `10^20` to a much smaller number like 100 if that helps you think about it.)  Figure out how you'd do that, then find a way to translate that into code.  And if there's one particular step you're having trouble translating, check the Javadoc first.  If you do that and you're still stuck, then ask us.

Comment: Thank you all guys for the advices,I'm really new to this forum,sorry I shouldn't have just asked for the codes.I somehow made it this far

Comment: import java.math.BigInteger ;
public class PROJECTV1
{
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    BigInteger bResult= bigFunctionExample_2();
            System.out.println(" => result_got:"+ bResult);
            System.out.println() ; //newline
    
            
          
  }// end_main

Comment: public static BigInteger bigFunctionExample_2()
  {
    
    BigInteger bSum = BigInteger.ZERO;
    BigInteger bTmp;
    String sSum;
   // BigInteger bResult =0;
    for (int i=1; ; i++) {
        bTmp = BigInteger.valueOf(i);
        bTmp = bTmp.pow(2); // i^2
        bSum = bSum.add(bTmp); // sum = i^2+ (i-1)^2 + ....
        sSum = bSum.toString();
        if ( sSum.length() >30)  {
          System.out.println("i="+i +" bSum ="+bSum);
          break;
        }//
    }//end_for
  
    return bSum; // result
  }// end_bigFunctionExample_2
}

Comment: It's running extremely long and it hasn't returned a value back,am I doing it right?

Comment: I'm a newbie here.Can you instruct me how to post codes in a proper way,sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, you have a line `bTmp.pow(2)`. That squares the numbers in your series, but you need to raise `bTmp` to the `bTmp` power. Java doesn’t seem to want to take a `BigInteger` as an argument to `pow`, but you could replace `pow` with another `for` loop.

Also, `sSum.length() >30` looks like it will only occur if your sum is greater than or equal to 10<sup>29</sup>. Is there a reason you convert the number to a string each time through the loop, rather than comparing the number to 10<sup>20</sup>? Perhaps you could put something like `bSum > bMax` as the test condition in your `for` loop, rather than leaving it blank and exiting with a `break`. Then you could make a new `BigInteger bMax` and set it to 10<sup>20</sup> at the start of your code.

For testing, you could set `bMax` to something small, like 100, and see if your program gives the correct result. You can calculate the first few steps of the series by hand to check your program.

Comment: I changed the power of bTmp to i and compare whether sSum has more than 21digits(which means it is larger than 10^20). I now have an answer,I will later try it with smaller values just as you suggested.Thank you so much!

Comment: @AnthonyHsieh Oh right, that's a better idea. I hope it works now.

Comment: yup,and the value is extremely large(of course).I don't have my computer now.I will test the program with smaller values to insure there are no flaws.Thanks for the advices :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a clue computing some factorials:

```
import java.math.*;

public class FactorialBig {
    public static BigInteger factorial(BigInteger n) {
        if (n.equals(BigInteger.ZERO))
            return BigInteger.ONE;
        else
            return n.multiply(factorial(n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int n = 0; n < 20; n++) {
            BigInteger f = factorial(new BigInteger(new Integer(n).toString()));
            System.out.printf("factorial(%2d) = %20s%n", n, f.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

You know you should save the above as a file named "FacotrialBig.java".